# how to use joins in my sql?

Tags: mysql

there are two tables tbldoctor and tblschedule

tbldoctor

```
 doc_id(PK)    docMrId        docfname
      1          22             manish
      2          23             rahul
      3          22             ashish
      4          24             ahemad
      5          22             narendra
      6          22             akshat
```

tblschedule

```
  doctor_id(FK)    mr_id       schedule_date
     1              22          2012-06-12
     1              22          2012-06-13
     3              22          2012-06-14
     3              22          2012-06-14
     4              24          2012-06-12
     4              24          2012-06-12
     5              22          2012-06-14
     5              22          2012-06-15
     5              22          2012-06-12
```

What i want is list of all doctorid and the count of particular doctor repeated in tblschedule table where schedule_date parameter and mr_id is provided here we are supposed mr_id =22  and schedule_date between 2012-06-01 to 2012-06-31

Output Should look like

```
  doc_id         docfname      count
    1               manish       2
    3               rahul        2
    5               narendra     3
    6               akshat       0
```

Comment: What you tried? Can you do it without the grouping/counting? Or without including the doctor's name? Then try to put the two together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select d.doc_id, docfname, count(mr_id) as count
from tbldoctor d
left outer join tblschedule s on s.doctor_id = d.doc_id
where mr_id = 22 
and schedule_date between '2012-06-01' and '2012-06-31'
group by s.doctor_id
```

### edit

```
select d.doc_id, 
       docfname, 
       sum(case when mr_id = 22 
                then 1 
                else 0 
           end) as count
from tbldoctor d
left outer join tblschedule s on s.doctor_id = d.doc_id
and schedule_date between '2012-06-01' and '2012-06-31'
group by s.doctor_id
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/257de/6)

### edit 2

how about

```
select d.doc_id, docfname, count(mr_id) as count
from tbldoctor d
left outer join tblschedule s on s.doctor_id = d.doc_id and mr_id = docmrid
where docmrid = 22 
and (schedule_date between '2012-06-01' and '2012-06-31' or mr_id is null)
group by s.doctor_id
order by d.doc_id
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65158/12)

Comment: It is working but not with 0 count there few doc_id which are not in tblschedule.

Comment: thank you sir this is working fine but not showing doctor with 0 count please help me out

Comment: See [this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/257de/3). It shows `0` count. (I left the where clause there to simplify the test)

Comment: but in the example you have not used where clause with mr_id=22, thats why it is showing 0 count

Comment: dear sir i want the only record from tbldoctor where mr_id=22 not other.

Comment: in my example in tbldoctor doc_id 3,5 and 6 is there which are having mr_id=22 but doc_id 6 is exist in tblschedule table it should be shown in output as 0 count.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure I've understood you, but this will give you a list of all doctor IDs, along with the number of schedule items for each in between two given dates.

```
SELECT tbldoctor.doc_id, COUNT(*) cnt
FROM tbldoctor d INNER JOIN tblschedule s
    ON d.doc_id = s.doctor_id
WHERE s.schedule_date BETWEEN '2012-06-12' AND '2012-06-15'
GROUP BY tbldoctor.doc_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `tbldoctor` JOIN `tblschedule` ON `tblschedule`.doctor_id(FK) = `tbldoctor`.doc_id(PK)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tbldoctor.doc_id, COUNT(*) cnt FROM tbldoctor d INNER JOIN tblschedule s     ON d.doc_id = s.doctor_id WHERE s.schedule_date BETWEEN '2012-06-12' AND '2012-06-15' GROUP BY tbldoctor.doc_id
```